Change Hydronic Circulation Pump Control?
Currently we have 5 hydronic zones controlled by 5 thermostats and control valves for air handlers with 1 hydronic circulator pump.  The circulator pump runs continuously if the outdoor temp is lower than the set point on it's temperature controller.
I would like to change the system so the circulator only runs when any of the thermostats are calling for heat.  The thermostats are wired to the air handlers (fan control) and control valves allow hot water (circulated by the hydronic curculator pump) into the air handlers.  The circulator pump is currently controlled by outside air temp with a temperature controller.
Is this a good idea?
How can it be accomplished?

So fit a relay into the supply wire to the pump controlled by the thermostats.

The thermostats are not controlling the pump.  The pump is controlled by a temperature controller.   There are no wires from the thermostats to the room where the ciculation pump is located.

Then you need to add some wires...

"There are no wires from the thermostats to the room where the ciculation pump is located." There would not be. Each thermostat runs its own air handler control, and each air handler control has a secondary switch activated when the thermostat activates the air handler control. These secondary switches are all wired in parallel to the boiler control. So any thermostat starts its own zone, and any zone can start the boiler. Look for a wire coming from one of your air handler controls to the boiler.

Thanks I will search out the wiring in more detail.


Is this a good idea?


5 hydronic zones controlled by 5 thermostats and control valves for air handlers with 1 hydronic circulator pump.

it might be a good idea, or it might not be; it depends on the piping scheme.  There are various pros/cons to pumping with 1 circ and using zone valves versus pumping with multiple circulators.


The circulator pump runs continuously if the outdoor temp is lower than the set point on it's temperature controller.

no




I would like to change the system so the circulator only runs when any of the thermostats are calling for heat

this is generally how it works, look up on youtube boiler control order of operation; that will be the easiest quickest way to get an explanation and understanding of how it should be and what you have incorrect.  If you are correct in stating your circ pump runs continuously when outdoor temp is below X° then that is not correct.  Unless your interpretation of if it works and I get heat that simply = correct; need a lot more information to understand what you have but first things that come to mind is a zone controller and a [maybe better] boiler controller is needed given what you did describe.  i.e. Taco Zone Controller (various models) and Hydrostat by Hydrolevel.  Because you said air handler (if you are not mistaken) it is not a conventional hydronic system with simple baseboard heat zones, so there's a lot more that needs to be discussed and identified.
